# Replacing Patterns In a List of Varying Length

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation

I am working with an array of data that may look something like this.

```
data={{0.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.},{1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.}}
```

I want to replace any sequence of ones that exceeds two in a row with the same number of zeros in order to maintain the original dimensions of the array.  I came up with the following to try to do this.

```
data /. {x__, PatternSequence[Repeated[1., {2}]], y__} -> {x}~Join~Table[0., {i, 2}]~Join~{y}

{{0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.},{1.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.}}
```

Unfortunately, it only replaces the first two ones in a sequence with zeros and leaves the rest.  That's not exactly what I was aiming for.

Comment: I also forgot something in my test data above.  These numbers are floating point numbers, as it is much faster to manipulate large arrays using floating point numbers.  So, my data looks something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}}

ReplaceRepeated[data, {x___, 
   z : Longest[Repeated[1, {2, Infinity}]], 
   y___} :> {x, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, Length@{z}], y}]

(*

{{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

*)
```

Or shorthand:

```
data //. {x___, z : Longest[Repeated[1, {2, Infinity}]], y___} :>
         {x, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, Length@{z}], y}
```

Per our comment conversation, a sketch of an idea to speed things for large arrays:

```
sa = SparseArray[data]["AdjacencyLists"];
diff = Differences /@ sa;
map = MapThread[Pick[#1, Append[#2, 0], 1] &, {sa, diff}];
split = Split[#, #1 == #2 - 1 &] & /@ map;
MapIndexed[If[#1 != {}, data[[First@#2, Append[#1, Last@#1 + 1]]] = 0] &, split, {2}];
```

Result in original `data` array. This is *hugely* faster on large arrays, but there's undoubtedly room to improve.

Update:

Here's where the structure of your data can be used to our advantage. By moving to the string domain to do the replacement work and then converting back to the binary, we can over triple the speed of the `SparseArray` technique:

```
result = With[{zz = FromCharacterCode[0],
      zo = FromCharacterCode[1],
      zt = FromCharacterCode[2], lst = #}, 
     ToCharacterCode[
      StringReplace[
       FixedPoint[
        StringReplace[#, {StartOfString ~~ zo ~~ zz -> zt <> zz, 
           zz ~~ zo ~~ zz -> zz <> zt <> zz, 
           zz ~~ zo ~~ EndOfString -> zz <> zt}] &, 
        FromCharacterCode[lst]], {zo -> zz, zt -> zo}]]] &[data];
```

Update 2:

As happens sometimes (particularly when one has been working on a similar problem and thinks "hmmmm, this seems the same..."), I *way* over-thought this.

```
Flatten /@ 
   Replace[Split /@ #, z:{Repeated[1, {2, Infinity}]} :> ConstantArray[0, Length@z], 
           {2}] &[data]
```

Is *much* faster. As with other solutions above using `Repeated`, replace the `2` with the desired minimum number of ones to replace. Also, for small minimums, direct pattern matching will be slightly faster, e.g.:

```
Flatten /@ 
   Replace[Split /@ #, z : {1, 1 ..} :> ConstantArray[0, Length@z], {2}] &[data]

Flatten /@ 
   Replace[Split /@ #, z : {1,1, 1 ..} :> ConstantArray[0, Length@z], {2}] &[data]
```

Will replace for minimums of 2 and 3 ones in sequence, respectively. Also, depending on packed status, using `Join@@@` in place of `Flatten/@` *might* speed things up a bit on large arrays.

For the specific case of replacing repeated ones of length 2 or more, the following is very fast (up to 10X the fastest above) when the sublists are long (as in say a 100x100000 array):

```
With[{ap = ArrayPad[#, {1, 1}]}, 
   Clip[ArrayPad[ap - RotateLeft[ap] - RotateRight[ap], {-1, -1}],
       {1,1}, {0, 0}]] & /@ data
```

I note you've changed the OP data - note you'll need to adjust some of the methods here to account for that (e.g., `FromCharacterCode` will not work with non-integer values, so conversion to that would be needed, and the patterns need to use `1.` vs `1`).

Comment: Thanks.  I knew there was probably a way to do it without indexing through it.  Hopefully this will be fast.  I am working with arrays on the order of {100,100000}

Comment: @Kane: this kind of pattern matching can get slow. I'd venture for large arrays you'll need something clever. I'll ponder it...BTW- you say in OP "exceeds 2", but your example includes 2 length. Which is the intent?

Comment: @Kane: Please see updated post. Perhaps you could test, advise if further fleshing-out warranted. Off to munch, but back later...

Comment: @Kane: Added a string-based method that is pretty quick - give it a whirl.

Comment: Ultimately, for the large arrays I am working with, what I want to do is replace any sequence of ones that are larger than 100 or maybe even 1000.  I'm not sure yet.  What I posted above was an example of what I am trying to do at a smaller scale so I can propose the question.

Comment: I like the idea of converting to a string.  However, it isn't apparent to me how I can adjust the number of ones in the pattern before making them zeros.  For instance, let's say I need to see 100 ones in a row before making them zeros.

Comment: @Kane: In the case of having some other minimum, you can use `Repeated` for strings too. However, check for update in a few minutes - I *way* over-thought this, there's a faster simpler way.

Comment: @rasher, you could use `0 z` instead of `ConstantArray[0, Length@z]`.

Comment: @kguler: Yep, and gives a minor perf. boost to boot.

Comment: Thanks guys.  This has been very helpful.  It is very fast and doing exactly what I had originally intended.  Unfortunately, it has led me to another problem that is very similar to this one.  What I am finding is that just looking for a minimum number of 1s in a row isn't good enough.  I am trying to carve out areas in my data where there is a high density of 1s without completely zeroing out everything.  This means that there could be some 0s sprinkled in randomly that break up the pattern and I still want that area zeroed out.  I would think this requires an entirely different approach?

Comment: @kane: Probably best to update OP with some concrete examples of input->output results, narrowing down what the "rules" for zeroing are. Yes, at the very least a modification of answers here will be needed, more likely a different method - expect it will be slower, since it's more complex...

Comment: @rasher I think I may just start a new question...

Comment: @Kane: Yes, perhaps referencing this post, because it is enough different to warrant a new question: You allude to a more complex incarnation that will probably bring out some interesting answers...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use `StringReplace`:

```
rF = With[{dt = #, num = #2},  PadLeft[#, Dimensions[dt]] &@
   (IntegerDigits /@ ToExpression /@ 
       (StringReplace[#, z : Repeated["1", {num, Infinity}] :> 
         StringReplace[z, "1" -> "0"]] &[IntegerString /@ FromDigits /@ dt]))] &

data = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}};
rF[data,2]
(* {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
rF[data,4]
(* {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
    {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}*)
```

Comparison with @rasher's string-based method:

```
rasherF =  With[{zz = FromCharacterCode[0], zo = FromCharacterCode[1], 
                zt = FromCharacterCode[2], lst = #}, 
            ToCharacterCode[StringReplace[
              FixedPoint[StringReplace[#, {StartOfString ~~ zo ~~ zz -> zt <> zz, 
                zz ~~ zo ~~ zz -> zz <> zt <> zz, 
                zz ~~ zo ~~ EndOfString -> zz <> zt}] &, 
                 FromCharacterCode[lst]], {zo -> zz, zt -> zo}]]] &;


rndData = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {100000, 100}];
resulta = rF[rndData, 2]; // Timing
(* {4.968750, Null} *)
resultb = rasherF[rndData]; // Timing
(* {3.671875, Null} *)
resulta = =resultb
(* True *)

rndData2 = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {792001, 111}];
resulta2 = rF[rndData2, 2]; // Timing
(* {43.609375, Null} *)
resultb2 = rasherF[rndData2]; // Timing
(* {32.328125, Null} *)
resulta2 == resultb2
(* True *)
```

Comment: This method appears to work with the test data above. However, when I use data on the order of {792001,111}, for some reason it doesn't work anymore.  For some reason it yielded {792001,104} array and it didn't replace any patterns of 1 to 0.

Comment: @Kane,I think this version fixes the problem (used the second argument of `PadLeft` to pad with the right number of zeros). It now gives the same output as rasher's method, but it is still considerably slower.

Comment: @kguler: We both over-thought this ;-), see my update.

Comment: @rasher, a-ha - that confirms the nagging hunch that this should have been much simpler:)

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
   {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3) and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
SequenceReplace[#, {1, 1, a : 1 ...} :> Splice @ Table[0, Length[{a}] + 2]] & /@ list
```

returns the accepted result

```
{{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
list = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}};

f = Function[x, Flatten[SequenceSplit[x, s : {1, 1, 1 ...} :> s] /. 
    s_ /; MatchQ[s, {1 ..}] :> s - 1]];

f /@ list

{{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```